# Replace old Bosch computer with Motronic?

Tags: computer, tuning

I have a 1996 B5254S engine that came with a Bosch LH-3.2/EZ-129K computer. The next model year 1997 they started using the Motronic 4.4 computer for this engine.

Can I just switch out the Bosch for the Motronic or will that not work?

My basic problem is that I can't tune the Bosch LH-3.2/EZ-129K and would like to have a computer that I can tune.

Comment: That is a good question. My gut is telling me it probably isn't that easy. Usually never is when it comes to wiring. :-)

Comment: I realize this is a Volvo, but what model is it you are trying to do this with? Is the 96 an 850 and the 97 an S70/V70? Even if it does have the same engine, you'd have to mate the wiring harness from the 97 to your 850.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I was thinking the same thing. And that wiring harness may not match the current engine configuration (location and type of connections).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you planning to alter in the engine's tuning?